# Denotation in Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have the following sentence: "John offends nobody."
I need to do three things. First, figure out what semantic types each node of a syntax tree refers to. Second, determine what each node in the tree specifically refers to. And third, calculate the truth-value of the sentence.

Now, I know that "John" refers to semantic type "e" and "offends" refers to semantic type $<e<e,t>>$.

Q: Is the denotation of "nobody,"then $<<e,<e,t>>,<e,t>>$? That is what I have; any tips or tricks or suggestions would be great.

Moving on: I know that "Offends" denotes a function $\lambda x. \lambda y. x$ offends $y$. (I think).

Q: How do I determine what "nobody" refers to, and what the denotation of the VP "offends nobody refers to"? I'm really stuck; does anyone have any tips or suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.